# How to click on an element with aria-hidden="true" using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have HTML as below

```
<div class="summary-row">
    <div class="text-center" id="summary-back">
        <a href="/Health/Dependents">
            <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-chevron-left fa-w-8 font-32" data-auto="back-btn" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fal" data-icon="chevron-left" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 256 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M238.475 475.535l7.071-7.07c4.686-4.686 4.686-12.284 0-16.971L50.053 256 245.546 60.506c4.686-4.686 4.686-12.284 0-16.971l-7.071-7.07c-4.686-4.686-12.284-4.686-16.97 0L10.454 247.515c-4.686 4.686-4.686 12.284 0 16.971l211.051 211.05c4.686 4.686 12.284 4.686 16.97-.001z"></path></svg><!-- <i class="fal fa-chevron-left font-32" data-auto="back-btn"></i> -->
        </a>
        </div>
```

And RemoteWebDriver unable to find the element and I assume its due to the hidden attribute, How can click on this element ?

Comment: Which element are you trying to locate?

Comment: The svg element which is a button with a hidden attribute.

Comment: You don't need to reach till the `<svg>` tag. Try to invoke the `click()` on the `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the element using JavaScriptExecutor like:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("summary-back"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("div.summary-row > div#summary-back > a[href=/Health/Dependents]"))).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class='summary-row']/div[@id='summary-back']/a[@href='/Health/Dependents']"))).Click();
  ```

Comment: @Rasika Can you provide me a feedback on this answer please?

Answer (score 0):

I just changed attribute "aria-hidden" from "true" to "false" and after that I clicked.

Perhaps that code can help you.

```
public void ClickElementHidden()
{
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("document.getElementsByClassName('svg-inline--fa fa-chevron-left fa-w-8 font-32')[0].setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'false')");
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#summary-back > a > svg")).Click();   
}
```